# Custom Owin Middleware Being Hit Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I have custom owin middlware setup that is pretty simple and was working as expected before I changed the handlers in the web.config and added this:

```xml
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I wanted to be able to handle all types of requests with my API and it seems that updating the handler this way is the only way to do it, but once I added this into the config file my custom owin middlware started to be hit twice for each request:

```
public class RequestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public RequestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        string name = context.Request.Headers["Repository"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Custom Owin Middlware Reqeusted");

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Why might this middleware all of a sudden start to get hit twice? I looked at the request for each time it was hit and everything looked the same. At first I thought one might be an OPTIONS request but they were both GET requests. This isn't being requested using CORS, but it was the only thing that stood out in my mind.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I changed the handler for .html files and am running into this same problem. One request, hits Invoke twice.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think what did it is removing the webDAV handler and module

Comment: <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules> and add this to handlers <remove name="WebDAV" />